# Merging cells in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

Is there any other way to merge cells in Excel using Apache POI library?

I was trying using the following, but its not working

```
// selecting the region in Worksheet for merging data
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A" + rowNo + ":D"
            + rowNo);

// merging the region
sheet1.addMergedRegion(region);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Throws an error? Upsets Excel? Merges a different region? Sits around all day watching tv? ;-)

Comment: cells do not merge..excel remains the same...

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use `sheet.addMergedRegion(rowFrom,rowTo,colFrom,colTo);`

example `sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,1,4));` will merge from B2 to E2. Remember it is zero based indexing (ex. POI version 3.12).

for detail refer [BusyDeveloper's Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: if after this, Excel says it has to repair the file, make sure you're not overlapping cells when merging

Comment: @golimar What do you mean by overlapping cells?

Comment: @JamesKleeh For example, creating one merged region A1+A2 and another merged region A2+A3

Comment: Note that there are two versions of CellRangeAddress:  the one to use is `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress` whereas the other one `org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress` is now deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267679/what-to-use-instead-of-deprecated-cellrangeaddress-valueof-in-apachepoi

Answer (score 13):

You can use :

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(startRowIndx, endRowIndx, startColIndx,endColIndx));
```

Make sure the CellRangeAddress does not coincide with other merged regions as that will throw an exception.

- If you want to merge cells one above another, keep column indexes same
- If you want to merge cells which are in a single row, keep the row indexes same
- Indexes are zero based

For what you were trying to do this should work:

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNo, rowNo, 0, 3));
```

Comment: The most wholesome answer. Also explains general guidelines for merging.

Answer (score 6):

I create a method that merge cells and put border if you want.

```
protected void setMerge(Sheet sheet, int numRow, int untilRow, int numCol, int untilCol, boolean border) {
    CellRangeAddress cellMerge = new CellRangeAddress(numRow, untilRow, numCol, untilCol);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellMerge);
    if (border) {
        setBordersToMergedCells(sheet, cellMerge);
    }

}  

protected void setBordersToMergedCells(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress rangeAddress) {
    RegionUtil.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best answer

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(start-col,end-col,start-cell,end-cell));
```

Comment: "The best answer" probably shouldn't include minus signs in variables. Also, the variables are outright wrong: columns are in the third and fourth position, not the first and second.

Answer (score 0):

*syntax is:*

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(start-col,end-col,start-cell,end-cell));
```

*Example:*

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4, 4, 0, 5));
```

Here the cell 0 to cell 5 will be merged of the 4th row.