# What to use instead of deprecated CellRangeAddress.valueOf in ApachePOI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, deprecated

I wanted to add conditional formatting in the region but One method which I saw in tutorial is deprecated. What to use instead of it.
Sample:

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.LT, "50");
    PatternFormatting fill2 = rule2.createPatternFormatting();
    fill2.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.index);
    fill2.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
            CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A6") //DEPRECATED
    };
    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
```

Answer (score 19):

You're using the wrong version of CellRangeAddress. [org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/util/CellRangeAddress.html) is deprecated, the one you should be using is [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html).

You need to use the *SS Common Spreadsheet Model* class, not the older HSSF-only one

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A6")
```