# How to read the colSpan and rowSpan of an Excel cell with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

Apache POI is a powerfull library but I can't find out how to read the `colspan` or `rowspan` of a cell.

I expected that the `XSSF` cell would have methods like `getColSpan()` but I just can't find the right hint - even google is not my friend in this case.

any Idea?

Comment: You mean span as in merged cells? If so this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716032/merging-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi

Comment: `Excel` is not using the concept of col-span and row-span. Instead it uses merged regions. See [XSSFSheet.getMergedRegions()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getMergedRegions()) for how to get them.