# Create line chart from apache poi for more than one series in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image: snapshot]

See the picture of the data sheet format. For this format i have to create a chart using apache poi. I tried considering an  [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/LineChart.java)  but I don't know how to create chart for multicolumn table using poi. please help.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You need to merge the corresponding cells. Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717238/3519000) will help.

Comment: I merged  excel document is ready but i need to generate Chart using apache poi

Comment: @EliasMP How does this not fit the rules in SO? The OP clearly stated points on using APACHE POI, Excel, and using Java in creating a line chart. How is broad?

Comment: @RinMinase As you can see... the question was edited since my comment... Cheers Mate