# Create rows or table inside cell in excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

I am using apache poi creating the excel. I want to create the structure shown in above image.

I am not aware how to customise as per the image.

Comment: Which aspect is unclear to you? How to create merged cells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging cells in Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716032/merging-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowFrom,rowTo,colFrom,colTo));
```

And specify the row numbers and column numbers accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to use the CellRangeAddress and come back